# Sorting table created by PHP, can't use query to sort

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a column I want to sort. Let me explain what the code does first.

As you can see, there are three select statements for and from three different tables(table names are in the code). The first query selects data from the table whereby I assign the retrieved data from the `id` column to `$device_id`.

The second query selects data from another table according to the value of `$device_id`(one value only). This will return multiple Board IDs(multiple values). If rows are returned, a table would be created.

In this table, a third query is executed to check for each board_id in the third table(`$table_tester_info`). If the board_id exists, then it would be displayed. Example: If there are 40 board_id and out of the 40 only 20 returned rows, the rows would be displayed in the table.

Now here's the problem. I want to sort the table according to a column in `$table_tester_info`(the third table) **however**, I can only use `ORDER BY` in the second query. That wouldn't be a problem but I want to sort according to a `column in $table_tester_info`, not `$table_tester_config`(the second table).

I'm using jQuery as well but I do not want to use any plugins to sort the DOM elements in HTML unless there is no other way(but I'm sure there are many ways, I just don't know it). I've tried sorting the assoc array(?) `$tester_name` or rather `$final_row['tester_name']` which was assigned to it.

Curerntly my table is not sorted when I add `ORDER BY` at the third query(which I know is wrong). Any help on this?

```
<?php

// Define database parameters
DEFINE ('DB_USER' ,'iqwdewqe');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'iqadeaqwe');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'qadewe');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'Tqweqwe');

// Connect to database
@mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) OR die ('Could not connect' 
                 .'to Database: '. mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db (DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not select the Database: '. mysql_error()); 

function searchDevice($device_name, $tester_type)
{
    $table_device = "TBL_DEVICE_LIST";
    $table_tester_config = "TBL_TESTER_CONFIG";
    $table_tester_info = "TBL_TESTER_INFO";

    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM $table_device WHERE device = '$device_name'
                                AND tester_type = '$tester_type'";
    $device_result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
    $device_row = mysql_num_rows($device_result);

    if($device_row)
    {
        $device_row = mysql_fetch_array($device_result);
        $device_id = $device_row['id'];
       // echo "Device ID: $device_id <br>";

        $query_string = "SELECT * FROM $table_tester_config WHERE device_id = '$device_id'";
        $config_result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die(mysql_error());
        $config_row = mysql_num_rows($config_result);

        if($config_row)
        {


            while($config_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($config_result))
            {
                $board_id = $config_row['board_id'];
                $oboard = $config_row['configuration'];
                 //echo "Board ID: $board_id <br>";

                //Query to check if board_id exists, 
                if exists then display value in while loop
                $query_string = "SELECT * FROM $table_tester_info 
                WHERE board_id = '$board_id' ORDER BY tester_name";
                $final_result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die(mysql_error());
                $final_row = mysql_num_rows($final_result);

                    if($final_row)
                    {
                        echo "<table border='1'>";
                        echo "<tr>
                        <th>Board ID</th>
                        <th>Tester Name</th>
                        <th>Board Name</th>
                        <th>Configuration</th>
                        <th>Log Created</th>
                        <th>New</th>
                        </tr>";
                        while($final_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($final_result))
                        {
                            $board_id = $final_row['board_id'];
                            $tester_name = $final_row['tester_name'];
                            $board_name = $final_row['board_name'];
                            $config = $final_row['config'];
                            $log_created = $final_row['log_created'];

                            echo "<tr>
                                        <td>$board_id</td>
                                        <td>$tester_name</td>
                                        <td>$board_name</td>
                                        <td>$config</td>
                                        <td>$log_created</td>
                                        <td>$oboard</td>
                                     </tr>";
                        }
                    }
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Device Name: $device_name with Tester Type: $tester_type.";
    }
}

?>

<?php

$action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

if($action=="search")
{
    $device_name = rtrim($_REQUEST['device_name']);
    $tester_type = rtrim($_REQUEST['tester_type']);

    echo searchDevice($device_name, $tester_type);
}

?>
```

Comment: Can't you just make this a single query?

Comment: @Ja͢ck If it's possible, I'm not sure how. I'm selecting the second table based on a value from the first table. Then I'm checking whether the multiple values returned from the second table are available in the third table. Currently still finding a way to make it into a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine queries 2 and 3 with a join. By using an inner join you only get a row if the join is successful.

ie:

```
select tti.*
from $table_tester_config ttc
inner join $table_tester_info tti
    on tti.board_id = ttc.board_id
where td.device = '$device_name' and td.tester_type = '$tester_type'
order by tti.tester_name
```

Then loop through those results.

Comment: Ahh yes I was doing this, I actually solved it but let me post it up as a question. It was something like this but I was figuring out how to combine all three.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jack and Chris for giving me the idea. The exact one that I needed is actually(I hard coded the data):

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM TBL_TESTER_INFO ti
INNER JOIN TBL_TESTER_CONFIG tc
ON ti.board_id = tc.board_id
INNER JOIN TBL_DEVICE_LIST dl
ON  dl.id = tc.device_id
WHERE dl.device = '53262'
AND dl.tester_type = 'UFLEX'
ORDER BY tester_name ASC;
```